# Print a spreadsheet with IMAGE formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone have tried to print a spreadsheet where inside there is a image formula?

The step to reproduce this issue are:
1)Create a new spreadsheet
2)Insert in a cell =Image("https://xxxxxxxx.jpg")
3)Try to print the spreadsheet

The result is a blank spreadsheet in chrome, firefox and IE.

I tryed also to use google apps script to export the spreadsheet to pdf, but the result is the same.

Dose anyone know a workaround?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try Google docs to download in Excel Format. Open the Excel sheet and then try to print it. it worked for me

Comment: I tried and it didn't worked for me. Printing or exporting the image still doesn't appear. Try to dowload or print this spreadsheet for example. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvJ-wt8pN1DXdGRHc0lhdDJNcThpX2tkZ2N2MEdkUXc&usp=drive_web#gid=0 It works for you? Are you using a Google Apps account or a @gmail.com account?

Comment: i am using @gmail.com account and it workes perfectly all the time

Comment: Which browser u have used. I tryed with Chrome Version 30.0.1599.66 m that i updated now, and Firefox 24.0. Which method u use to export in excel? When the file is open, you use File->Export as-> .xlsx?

Comment: i am using Google Chrome Version 29.0.1547.76 m. and yes i used the same method as u typed

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste to Google document, then print it - that's the only method that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

file > Download > webpage html.(zipped)
then open the downloaded file and print

this will work